# How can I call a function based on a string name

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have a function that assigns column definition to my grid. There is one key called valueGetter which i need to assign the function to call to get the value for this column. The problem i am facing is that my API returns this value as a string.

When I set it via

> valueGetter: column.valueGetter,

it looks like this **valueGetter: "this.getSellerAgentandOffice"**
and it does not work. But if i manually set it to **valueGetter: this.getSellerAgentandOffice** it works. So the question is how can I set the column.valueGetter String value as a function name ?

Also just as some additional info when i tried to use

> valueGetter: this[column.valueGetter],

i am getting following error

[image: myValueGetter]

To make it more clear about the issue i included a [StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-3ugco1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Are you asking about `this['getSellerAgentandOffice']` ?

Comment: Nope, the value of column.valueGetter = this.getSellerAgentandOffice  as string. And i need to set the valueGetter Key with the function name of column.valueGetter but not as string

Comment: This might be answerable with a little more code to set the context, but my first thought was along the lines of @Hafthor.  It's not clear what's a string, whether the string contains "this" or "column" or what "column" refers to, etc.

Comment: I provided some more code sample of how it is used. As for the string its the name of the fuction. It can or can not contain the this part as i can change what is stored but originaly started with this before i ran into issue

Comment: `this[valueGetter]`, without the quotes (or maybe you need remove the "this" form the string "this.getSellerAgentandOffice", `this[valueGetter.split('.')[1]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the question was down voted 3 times even so i provided code and working sample. But what would one expect from some of these guys.

In any case if someone should run into a similar issue below is the code that fix the issue as i guess the error was due to fact that it could be possibly undefined or nothing.

```
 const valueGetter =   column.valueGetter as string;
 valueGetterFunction = this[valueGetter] || '';
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a function on an object, simply reference it the same way you would if it were a property, and then invoke it with parentheses.

```
this.myFunction(param1, param2);
```

becomes

```
this["myFunction"](param1, param2);
```

Note that you CANNOT do this with simple named functions, unless they happen to be global.

```
window["myFunction"](param1, param2);
```

that is a function like myFunction below is not reachable except directly.

```
(function() {
  // cannot be reached by string
  function myFunction(a, b) { ... }
})();
```

Comment: This is not the issue for me, i can specify the function fine if i use the this.getSellerAgentandOffice and manually set it, the problem is when i use the value commoning from the api since in that case the value is not the function but the string with the value of this.getSellerAgentandOffice